# In MongoDB, can we dispense with the traditional user ID?

Tags: mongodb

A classical relational database would have a field like USER_ID which would typically be an auto incrementing number. MongoDB has a document id which look something like the following

> 4f90e98277f6426c0a000001

Can this completely replace USER_ID?  I guess what I'm basically asking is, in terms of searching, inserting and indexing is it just as fast as an auto incrementing number?  If

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unlikely that you'll face performance issues because of primary key being ObjectID rather than an integer. You'll sooner be affected by data size. I wouldn't worry about that.

ObjectID brings several benefits:

- it is globally unique (you can create new ids in the application without consulting the database);
- sharding support (no need to synchronize auto-increment sequences between shards);
- monotonically increases with time (and includes actual timestamp, so you don't have to have separate `created_at` field if you only want to sort by insertion time);

Comment: Not only monotonically increasing with time, but includes an actual timestamp (there are function to extract it).

Comment: Yes, I thought it's implied :)

Comment: Is it okay to return Object id in a public facing api? I guess the most you can tell is I'm using MongoDb and some machine specific info.

Comment: Yeah. So what? Your system should be protected in any case. No matter what you use, mysql or mongodb.